# Not getting latitude and longitude in textview

Tags: android, mysql, latitude-longitude

I am working with a project to get latitude and longitude and also send that lat and long to my server. But I didn't get the latitude and longitude. I cannot find out where the error occur.

```
private String Tag="MainActivity";
String lat="", lon="";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btnLocation = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLocation);
    btnLocation.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Acquire a reference to the system Location Manager

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) AddressActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            // Define a listener that responds to location updates

            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                    // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
                    lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());

                    lon = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());

                    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLoc);

                    tv.setText("Your Location is:" + lat + "--" + lon);
                }

                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
            };
            // Register the listener with the Location Manager to receive location updates
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }
    });

    Button btnSend = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            postData(lat, lon);
        }
    });



}

public void postData(String la, String lo) {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet  htget = new HttpGet("http://192.168.1.2/.../"+la+"/"+lo);

    try {
        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(htget);
        String resp = response.getStatusLine().toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, resp, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you add the permission for getting location in android manifest file

Comment: yes, i add permisssion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get lastKnowLocation from provider - `GPS`:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) AddressActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Location gpsLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

You parsing of `String` from `Double` is incorrect, Try to parse:

```
lat = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
lon = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
tv.setText("Your Location is:" + lat + "--" + lon);
```

Comment: Thanks , i didn't getting the values, is there any error in my code?

Comment: @Jincy did you tried this code, if tried and still not working. Open google maps from real device and get the current location from there and come back to your app, It will fetch last location from google maps app and will display here.!

Comment: @Jincy, Ask that question separately. Don't forget to upvote :)

Comment: Thanks. I got the answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
lat = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
lon = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
```

instead

```
lat = Double.toString(location.getLatitude());
lon = Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
```

Hope this vl work for you :-)

Comment: thanks. But it is not working. Is there any problem in location listener? That line is not working.